# Log4J2: change programmatically message color

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

If I use ANSI code inside log message, Log4J2 print it also in file.log not only on console.
I added `appender.rollingfile.layout.disableAnsi=true` in configuration file for Log4J2, but it doesn't remove ANSI code in `%msg`.

This is the code:

```
log.info(String.format("%sDONE.%s", Utility.ANSI_RED, Utility.ANSI_RESET));
```

How can I change the color of the message dynamically?
Thanks.

Comment: How is this question related to `JavaFX` or `Netbeans`?

Comment: Do it in the logger configuration.  If you hardcode the ANSI sequences in your log string, they go everywhere.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen ok but I want to change the color programmatically and not hard code it. How can I do?

Comment: Currently you _are_ hardcoding it.  What do you _really_ want to achieve?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'd like to print to console colored message or a colored portion of it and remove ANSI code in text file